# Comparing tuple elements against integers with Python

Tags: python, list, compare, tuples

I am having a hard time converting data. I select the data from my database, which is returned in tuple format. I try to convert them using `list()`, but all I get is a list of tuples. I am trying to compare them to integers which i receive from parsing my JSON. What would be the easiest way to convert and compare these two?

```
from DBConnection import db 
import pymssql
from data import JsonParse

db.execute('select id from party where partyid = 1')
parse = JsonParse.Parse()

for row in cursor:
    curList = list(cursor)

i = 0 

for testData in parse:
    print curList[i], testData['data']
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
(6042,) 6042

(6043,) 6043

(6044,) 6044

(6045,) 6045
```

Comment: try `for row in cursor: print int(row[0])`, if casting it to `int` is needed at all. BTW: `curList = list(cursor)` does not make sense within the loop does it? (i.e. `cursor` does not change, whereas `row` does)

Comment: @Pynchia: that is assuming that `testData['data']` is also an integer. :-) We can't tell from this sample if it is a string, for example.

Comment: yes, you are right. I am referring to the row read from the DB only. and cursor is not even defined/assigned, in the code shown.

Comment: Why are you using `db.execute()` instead of `cursor.execute()`? How would the `db` know what connection to execute the query on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL results always come as *rows*, which are sequences of columns; this is true even if there is just one column in each row.

Next, you are executing the query on the `db` object (whatever that may be), but are iterating over the cursor; if this works at all is more down to luck. You'd normally execute a query on the cursor object.

If you expect just one row to be returned, you can use `cursor.fetchone()` to retrieve that one row. Your `for row in cursor` loop is actually *skipping the first row*.

You could use:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select id from party where partyid = 1')
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

to retrieve the first column of the first row, or you could use tuple assignment:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select id from party where partyid = 1')
result, = cursor.fetchone()
```

If you do need to match against multiple rows, you could use a list comprehension to extract all those `id` columns:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select id from party where partyid = 1')
result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

Now you have a list of `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

`print curList[i][0], testData['data']`

Or how about:

```
for db_tuple, json_int in zip(cursor, parse):
   print db_tuple[0], json_int
```